# generated objects via wsimport , can not call in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, jax-ws, wsimport

I have tried all methods to run ws for two days, but I couldn't. I generated webservices as object classes via wsimport (jaxws)  . ( https://repservice.automatic.com.tr/automaticreport.asmx?wsdl )

In Spring MVC I couldn't get response.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String defaultPage(Model model) {
        AutomaticReport service = new  AutomaticReport();
        Holder<Integer> getFletLimitResult = null;
        Holder<String> result = null;
        AutomaticReportSoap response = service.getAutomaticReportSoap();
        response.getFletLimit("username", "password", "101732", getFletLimitResult, result);
        System.out.println(getFletLimitResult+ "  - "  + result);
                return "home";

    }
```

Comment: And where do you set your webservice connection parameters?

Comment: As i see on examples webservice connection url has been already added in automaticreport..class  . Other parameters are being sent by request functions.

Comment: Did you try running it outside Spring... When you say you don't get any response, what do you mean?  Is everything null?

Comment: Yes i did. SoapUI returns result correctly. Output s are null in spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holder-s are the class object. For this reason, We have to allocate object.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String defaultPage(Model model) {
        AutomaticReport service = new  AutomaticReport();
        Holder<Integer> getFletLimitResult = new  Holder<Integer>();
        Holder<String> result = new  Holder<String> ();
        AutomaticReportSoap response = service.getAutomaticReportSoap();
        response.getFletLimit("username", "password", "101732", getFletLimitResult, result);
       System.out.println(getFletLimitResult.value.toString() + "  -  "  + result.value.toString());
                return "home";

    }
```